# How can I add prettier to my glitch projects?

Tags: node.js, containers, prettier

I am creating small services on glitch and wanted to fork a typescript project ([here](https://glitch.com/~typescript-starter) you have a starter, to implement an oAuth gate.

I added a `.prettierrc` file, and added the husky, lint-staged packages, and a precommit script to run prettier on staged files, but it does not seem to take effect.

Any hand on this? I assume it should be rather simple.

Comment: I can't create yet a tag for Glitch, but I assume it is a topic where a lot of newbie questions are going to be made on, and it's from the creators of Stackoverflow, but don't know how to submit "Glitch" as a proposal before the 1500 points

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Glitch but it doesn't seem to commit when you edit the project so the `lint-staged` approach won't work.

I guess your best option is to run Prettier via the project's Console (click `Logs` and then `Console` to open it).